# How to create nested objects by returning objects in array with reduce in js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have an array, how to create a new object in another object by nesting each element of this array

```
let newArr = ['Parent', 'Child']
```

I want to convert this array to this format

```
  Parent[Child]={}
```

I should be able to loop this array and format it according to the length of the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
['a', 'b', 'c'].reduceRight((nest, key) => ({ [key]: nest }), {});
// { a: { b: { c: {} } } }
```